# Send data periodically to server in android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, alarmmanager

I'm trying to add a feature in one of my existing android app where the app should send the GPS co-ordinates every minute to server after the user logs in and stop sending as the app closes. I want to use scheduler kind of thing which runs in background and send the co-ordinates every minute.
Additionally i have a method that returns the GPS co-ordinates. Also if the internet on user's device is not available then the co-ordinates has to be stored in local database(tables are already in place) and later on send the list of co-ordinates whenever internet is available on user log-in.

I have considered few options and need some suggestions on which one to use:

1. AlarmManager: According to Google's [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#tradeoffs)- "It may not be the best choice for your app, particularly if you need to trigger network operations"
2. JobScheduler API: Suits my purpose but its included in Android 5.0 API 21, and my app is developed for API 9.
3. GCM with SyncAdapter: I'm not sure if this requires a lot of work and serve my purpose.

If anyone has used any of these services and has an opinion please do suggest on which one should i use for my scenario.

Thanks
~S

Comment: FYI: There is an unofficial [JobSchedulerCompat](https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat) lib that supports API 10+

Comment: wrap all your logic into IntentService and schedule it using AlaramManager. This saves your device battery life too.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) with either [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager)(JobScheduler type functionality on pre lollipop) or [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

The foreground service would require a notification making it clear to the user that your app is active, and allow it to keep running when the screen is off etc.

AlarmManager is more exact WRT scheduled time of running, while GcmNetworkManager is better about running tasks at a time that is best for the system as a whole, batching calls to optimize for battery life, checking for network connectivity before executing etc.

[SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) can provide similar options to GcmNetworkManager, but was not intended for one way sending of data up to the server, so SyncAdapter may be overkill for this.

Answer (score 2):

Google suggest if your app has to poll location continuously in background then use `FusedLocationApi` which will trigger after given interval and you will get a callback. Check the entire implementation here on google's training section.
[Adding Location in your app](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

Basically what you have to do here is create a **location update request** and **set an interval** for which you want to get an update(in your case it may be 1 min) and then set the priority(High accuracy, power balanced etc) then have **callback** for location updates and connect the `fusedLocationService` in either `onCreate()` or `onStart` of your activity. Done, your will get location updates for that interval.

Make sure you are disconnecting the service when you are not using it.

For updating these location to server I think you should do batch upload again it depends on the usages of your app.

agreeing with @kroikie for syncAdapter if you just have one way data flow then you should not use syncAdapter but should do batch upload like you can save 100(this number can be changed based on connected network type and battery level) location locally and then upload all of them in one go.

Comment: thanks, but i already have a procedure in place to get the location co-ordinates. But according to your answer i have to rely on the callback method to get the GPS cordinates, so what if moved to another activity, do i have to implement the callback method in every activity i have in my app?

Comment: i have edited my question please have a look; i'm more interested in having a job which runs on specific time intervals regardless of which activity i'm in.

Comment: This is exactly same thing I have done in one of my app. FusedLocation has 2 apis one for for foreground and other for background. To implement FusedLocation you have to use service which will run in background. See the link I have given in my answer. Service will run irrespective of your visible activity.

Comment: thanks again Ankit, fusedLocation api is quit useful and fits to my use-case. Only thing i'm now concerned about is how do i send these co-ordinates to server, because what i'm currently using to send data to server in my app is AsyncTask which is another background service. You've mentioned batch upload in your answer, can you please elaborate it.

Comment: By Batch upload I mean you can define some rules like 
1) Dont't send each location data immediately to server but save it in local db and send X no of location data to server in one go.
2) This X can be changed based on Data connectivity(More on WiFi but less on 3G and much less on 2G), battery status and user activity(like less if he is moving or more if he is standing)
In this way you may reduce battery consumption by almost 15-20% although your server may not have updated data but in mobile world battery is very critical.